# Appending and Executing dynamic OrderBy in Mule

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

In my application, the values for sorting is coming in Query Param and it can have 0 or more fields dynamically in any order. Now, I have to do the sorting on the basis of this.

**Input Payload**

```
 [
  {
    "studentId": "1234",
    "admissionNo": "KG87265-2021",
    "admissionDate": "2021-04-02T15:44:04Z",
    "fee": 3789.98,
    "currencyCode": "USD"
  },
  {
    "studentId": "87365",
    "admissionNo": "ONE883887-2021",
    "admissionDate": "2020-09-07T05:32:04Z",
    "fee": 8789.54,
    "currencyCode": "USD"
  },
  {
    "studentId": "36366",
    "admissionNo": "KG9838-2021",
    "admissionDate": "2019-02-01T09:22:04Z",
    "fee": 83883.98,
    "currencyCode": "USD"
  },
  {
    "studentId": "828888",
    "admissionNo": "NINE2223-2021",
    "admissionDate": "2016-04-01T15:44:04Z",
    "fee": 37989.98,
    "currencyCode": "USD"
  }
 ]
```

The URL is like
`http://localhost:8081/api/test?$orderby="admissionDate Desc, admissionNo,studentId"`

I am creating a variable and dynamically preparing the orderBy clause for my dataweave.

My variable is `orderByColumns = orderBy $.admissionDate[-1..0] orderBy $.admissionNo orderBy $.studentId`

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
  result: (payload) ++ vars.orderByColumns
}
```

Remember, `payload` is an array of objects and when I append the variable `orderByColumns` But in this case Mule takes it as String and gives output like this.

```
  "entries": [
    "orderBy $.admissionDate",
    "orderBy $.admissionNo",
    "orderBy $.studentId"
  ]
}
```

**Expected Output**

Result should be sorted with admissionDate in descending order and then by admissionNo and studentId

So, now I wanted to know if is there anyway by which orderBy can be escaped in Mule 4? or some other work around?

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: Can you post a sample input , sample URL (with query params) and what you expect the output to be ?

Comment: Thanks Salim. I have added these values onto original question.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Make sure that you post the script that you are working with , an input that you are using and the expected output corresponding to that input. Without these, it all is a guessing game for someone to solve this.

Comment: As well, is there a reason you would do orderBy $.columnA orderBy $.columnB orderBy $.columnC and not orderBy ($.columnA ++ $..columnC ++$.columnC) ?

Comment: There is not any specific reason but both would work isn't it?

Comment: Both would work while its easy to construct the summation sequence dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your input payload will be an array of objects, you can use the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var orderByFieldsStr = "columnC,ColumnA,columnB" //attributes.queryParams.orderby
var orderByFields=orderByFieldsStr splitBy "," //attributes.queryParams
//calculates the key concatenating the column values for each column in orderByFields
fun getKey(item) = 
  (orderByFields map ((field, index) -> item[field] default "")) joinBy  "_"
---
//Using Harshank Bansal's suggestion:
payload orderBy getKey($)

// Original suggestion
/*
(
    (payload map ((item, index) -> 
    item ++ {key: getKey(item)} //1. gets the key for each item
    )) orderBy ((item, index) -> item.key) //2. sorts the objects using the calculated key
) map ((item, index) -> item - "key") //3. get rid of the key used for sorting
*/
```

The idea is to create a key for each item containing the values of the column specified in the query params (respecting the order of the columns), and sort the objects based on that key. Once the ordering is done, we get read of the temporary key we used to sort the objects. This last step could be ignored if keeping the key attribute in each object is not an issue.

Update: actually, it's not necessary to add and remove the key: you can use directly the getKey function as the orderBy argument (credits to Harshank Bansal for pointing that out).

Update2: given the new context, you can use the following DataWeave expression to dynamically sort your payload using the provided query string (including desc or asc qualifiers):

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::Runtime
output application/json
// Replace the orderByColumn var by the 'orderBy' queryParam:
// var orderByColumns=attributes.queryParams["orderBy"]
var orderByColumns="admissionDate desc,studentId desc" splitBy  ","

fun getFieldName(field) = (trim(field) splitBy  " ")[0]

fun orderByField(items, field) = 
    (if (lower(trim(field)) matches /.*[ ]+desc/)
      items orderBy (
            try(() -> -$[getFieldName(field)]) orElse (() -> $[getFieldName(field)][-1]))
    else
      items orderBy $[getFieldName(field)])

fun orderByFieldIndex(items, fields, index) =
    flatten(
        if (index < sizeOf(fields)-1) 
            ((orderByField(items, fields[index]) ) groupBy ((item, index1) -> 
                item[(trim(fields[index]) splitBy  " ")[0]])
            ) pluck ((value, key, index1) -> 
                orderByFieldIndex(value, fields, index + 1)
            )
        else
            orderByField(items, fields[index]))

fun orderByFields(items, fields) = 
    orderByFieldIndex(items, fields, 0)
    
---
orderByFields(payload, orderByColumns)
```

Comment: Why do we need to add the temporary key and then remove it. Can't we write `payload orderBy getKey($)` directly?

Comment: You're absolutely right, Harshank. Honestly, I thought DataWeave would only sort the objects using an existing object attribute (in this case, key). You're suggestion works like a charm. I've updated the answer to reflect your suggestion. Thank you very much for pointing that out!

Comment: No it is not working as expected and the result with above solution and hardcoding of columns payload orderBy $.columnB gives separate result. The latter one shows better.

Comment: Could you please provide the input payload you are using as well as the columns you are using to order the records? Thanks.

Comment: @olamiral, I have edited the question and provided the sample input. You can change the data accordingly. But I also thought a way where I could have added the required colums with payload like                                                                                          
         `payload orderBy $.admisssionNo` In this case I wanted to have `admissionNo` in a variable and just append that variable with `payload orderBy` but it is throwing error and not working without `$.` So, If I am skipping this then it takes this as String

Comment: @Ashish Please, take a look at Update2: the proposed DW expression should work.